# Change the text at the same time with the image

Tags: jquery, jsonp, image

I have this slideshow with the images coming from a JSON feed. The images have the alt attribute taken from the feed but I would like to display the value of the alt on the image. This doesn't work as it only displays the first alt from the first image.

How should I do it?

This is the line I will have to modify:

```
htmlString += '<img src="' + item.url_m + '" alt="' + item.title + '"><span class="etc">"'+item.title+'"</span>';
```

And here is the complete code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) { 
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lon = position.coords.longitude;

        var JSONURL = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=d512a7bb4b7c0a6eb65d5095464ebf3f&format=json&privacy_filter=1&media=photos&tag=london&has_geo=1&accuracy=11&content_type=1&extras=geo,owner_name,url_m&page=1&per_page=20&radius_units=km&radius=5&lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon+"&jsoncallback=?";
  jQuery.getJSON( JSONURL, getJSONimages); 
  function getJSONimages(data) {
    var htmlString = "";
    $.each(data.photos.photo, function(i,item){
        htmlString += '<img src="' + item.url_m + '" alt="' + item.title + '"><span class="etc">"'+item.title+'"</span>';
    });      
    $('#slideshow').html(htmlString); 
    $('#slideshow').slideshow({
                timeout: 3000,
                type: 'random',
                fadetime: 2000
            });      
  }         
    });
}
else {    

}         
  })
```

I have tried like that but doesn't work?

`var display_alt = $("#slideshow img").attr("alt");` and then display the display_alt var in the span but again, the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

`$("#slideshow img")` selects all the images that are descendants of the `#slideshow` element. If you want to get the alt attribute for a specific image you need to narrow your search using something like:

```
$("#slideshow img").eq(1).attr('alt');//this will select the second image in the set
```

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/eq

```
$("#slideshow img").eq($("#slideshow img").index(current_slide_element)).attr('alt');//this will select the image in the set that matches the element stored in the `current_slide_element` variable
```

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/index

Many times slideshow plugins will add a class to the current slide or store the current slide index in an accessible variable. You can use these methods to find the index of the current slide to get the alt tag for that specific slide. Without more information that's about as precise as I can get.

Comment: my slideshow is extremely simple and it uses inline CSS with use of z-index. I understand your point but I still don't understand how to implement it, I will do some more research and try and find a way to select the photo and apply the title accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It travels through each `<img>` and copies its `alt` attribute into `<span class="etc">`:

```
$("#slideshow img").each(function(){
  var alt = $(this).attr("alt");
  $(this).next("span.etc").html(alt);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I have tried placing it in my loop, before, after, in between, I don't understand what is wrong and even if I understand your code (I am a complete beginner and I was able to write what I've done so far with help from forums and intense research), I am not able to understand exactly where to implement it :/.

Comment: will I be allowed to post a fiddle?